# How to design a regex used for searching a pattern, rather than validating a pattern?

Tags: regex, search, pattern-matching, automata, dfa

As we learned, given a regex pattern (e.g., `A B A B A C`), we can convert it to a DFA. In this example, it would be like a chain (you can test it [here](http://hackingoff.com/compilers/regular-expression-to-nfa-dfa)).

This "chain-like" DFA can tell if a given string match the pattern or not (i.e., accept/reject it); But it **cannot tell if there is any occurrence within the string and identify all of them**.

**Example:**
Suppose this is the to-search string: `A B C A B A B A B A C A B C`

Although there is an occurrence starting from the 6th character, the "chain-like" DFA cannot tell this. All it can do is to **reject** this string.

**Question**: Is it possible to design a regex that support such functionality?

(Note: I understand this question is kind of confusing; I would like to clarify it confuses you.)

Comment: I assume you're talking about ["classical" regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Regular_expression#Formal_definition), as studied in formal language theory, rather than of the regexp matching syntax found in many programming languages (which is a fairly distant descendant of the classical notation).

Comment: It's clearly possible to do what you ask, since most programming languages have a "replace regexp" function, which requires that it determine where the match occurred. Also, the "match regexp" operations often return a result containing the substring that matched.

Comment: For a very simple example, so the `-o` option to `grep` on Linux; instead of showing the entire line that matched, it just shows the portion of the line that matched the regexp.

Comment: @Barmar Good point. I am interested in how those "match regexp" operations translate the user defined regex to the searching functionality. As I shown, a regex is only used for examining if a string should be accepted or not (different from searching)

Comment: Presumably as it's stepping through the input data, when the DFA matches something it sets a variable to the current index. It just needs one variable for the position where the match started, and another for the end.

Comment: There are many open-source regexp libraries, you could just take a look at one of them to see how it works.

Comment: The original Thompson paper  from 1969 is also still a good read.

Answer (score 0):

The language of strings containing the substring `ABABAC` is matched by the regular expression:

```
.*ABABAC.*
```

Where the symbol `.` denotes a subexpression that matches any single input symbol (e.g. `(A|B|C)`, if the input language only has the symbols `A`, `B` and `C`).  To tell if a string has the substring `ABABAC`, you can build an NFA or a DFA from this regular expression, and check if it accepts your string.

Determining the *location* of the substring in the input string is not possible with a (single) standard N/DFA, simply because an N/DFA is defined to only return one bit of information (accept/reject).  However, it is possible to implement an "augmented N/DFA" that, in addition to matching the input, also keeps track of where in the string each state transition last occurred; this information is enough to efficiently reconstruct the location of the substring.

Comment: Glad to see you bring this up. Maybe `.*(ABABAC)*.*` can find multiple matches, right?

Comment: Not precisely, no; it finds adjacent repeats of `ABABAC`, zero or more. But this is not a particularly well-crafted regex. The  trailing `.*` is superfluous both in theory and in practice. The expression `(.*ABABAC)* would find zero or  more repetitions anywhere in a string.